# setting componenets by using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using GridBagLayout to locate components on panel but it is not working like it has to be. Location of components is not affecting by changing x and y values somebody please help explain what mistake i am making here Thanks in advance :)

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LMS extends JFrame {
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel RegNum, Name, FatherNam, MotherNam, DateBirth, BloodGrp, Email, Gender, RegDate, Desig, photo;
    JTextField RegNuumText, FatherNamText, MotherNamText, EmailText, DesigText;
    JList BloodGrpList;
    JSpinner DateSpi;

    // Constructor
    public LMS() {
        this.setTitle("Library Managment System");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(700, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // this.setResizable(false);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        // GridBagLayout bag = new GridBagLayout();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // Creating Labels
        RegNum = new JLabel("Registration Number");
        Name = new JLabel("Full Name");
        FatherNam = new JLabel("Father's Name");
        MotherNam = new JLabel("Mother's Name");
        DateBirth = new JLabel("Date Of Birth");
        BloodGrp = new JLabel("Blood Group");
        Email = new JLabel("Email");
        Gender = new JLabel("Gender");
        RegDate = new JLabel("Registration Date");
        Desig = new JLabel("Designation");
        photo = new JLabel("Photo");

        // creating Text Fields
        RegNuumText = new JTextField(30);
        FatherNamText = new JTextField();
        MotherNamText = new JTextField();
        EmailText = new JTextField();
        DesigText = new JTextField();

        // mainPanel.add(RegNum);
        addComp(mainPanel, RegNum, 0, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        addComp(mainPanel, RegNuumText, 0, 1, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
        this.add(mainPanel);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel thePanel, JComponent comp, int xPos, 
            int yPos, int compWidth, int compHeight, int place, int stretch) {

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        gridConstraints.gridx = xPos;
        gridConstraints.gridy = yPos;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = compWidth;
        gridConstraints.gridheight = compHeight;
        gridConstraints.weightx = 1;
        gridConstraints.weighty = 1;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridConstraints.anchor = place;
        gridConstraints.fill = stretch;

        thePanel.add(comp, gridConstraints);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LMS();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the intended layout of the GUI at standard size, and with more width & height to show how the extra space should be distributed.

Comment: didn't get it could you please explain further more?

Comment: @HasnainAhmadKhan Can you provide an example of your expected output and the current output for comparision

Comment: i am expecting label "RegNam" upper left corner i.e x=0 & y=0. But it is displaying at center of frame

Comment: @HasnainAhmadKhan You mis-understand how layout management works, it's not pixel based. I'd suggest that you start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) in more detail

Comment: @HasnainAhmadKhan Also, you've set the anchor position of `RegNum` to `EAST` which will make align to the right side of the panel...

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayout is not the easiest one, you have to play a little with it. Maybe these lines help you to achieve what you wanted. They will put the label in the upper left corner and the Textfield right behind it.

Note, that there are panels defined as place holders - they will fill the empty space.

```
    addComp(mainPanel, RegNum, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(mainPanel, RegNuumText, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(mainPanel, new JPanel(), 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
    addComp(mainPanel, new JPanel(), 0, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL);
```

You also need to change your helper method a little:

```
    gridConstraints.weightx = stretch == GridBagConstraints.NONE || stretch == GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL ? 0 : 1;
    gridConstraints.weighty = stretch == GridBagConstraints.NONE || stretch == GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL ? 0 : 1;
```

I think this should do the trick. Maybe you should define two or three helper methods, so you don't need to set all parameters every time. From my experience, very rarely you will need to define the anchor and only some times you might want to stretch components. Most of the time, for me, it is just puting stuff into the right bags (x, y, sometimes: width, height).

Edit: maybe it would help to put setVisible() at the end of the definition, not the beginning.

Comment: Yes i think you are right I started studying layout managers again from the scratch. :/